# Why is this NSTimer crashing?

Tags: swift

When I run this code through, before it even runs the NSTimer for the first time, it crashes, outputting:*"libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"* in the console. I've been thinking avout this for a few days now, and can't find a solution, any help will be welcome, thanks.

EDIT: The code is located within a IBAction, and the purpose of this is to change some cell's color in the collection view to white or black, depending on the value of it's correspondent integer in the array simulatedUniverse[universeCounter]. Before I added the NSTimer it was working, but as the screen was updating too fast, I could only see the last pattern displayed, sorry for not adding this before.

CONSOLE OUTPUT:
2016-03-06 23:44:54.935 Digiverse[33095:2612091] -[Digiverse.SimulatorViewController paintUniverse]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f91c504c6c0
2016-03-06 23:44:54.942 Digiverse[33095:2612091] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Digiverse.SimulatorViewController paintUniverse]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f91c504c6c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105f92e65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107cd2deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105f9b48d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105ee890a ___forwarding_** + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105ee84b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00000001063780d1 **NSFireTimer + 83
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105ef2c84 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 20
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105ef2831 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1089
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105eb4241 __CFRunLoopRun + 1937
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105eb3828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    10  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010a5a8ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001067af610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    12  Digiverse                           0x0000000105da524d main + 109
    13  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001087db92d start + 1
    14  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

```
let simAlgorithm = UniverseSimulationAlgorithm()

func checkPopPlaces ( strPlaces: [String]? ) -> [Int]? {

    var populatedPlaces: [Int]?

    if strPlaces! == [] {

        if size < 7 {
            populatedPlaces = nil
        }
        else {
            populatedPlaces = []
        }

    }
    else {

        populatedPlaces = []

        for str in populatedStringPlaces! {
            populatedPlaces!.append(Int(str)!)
        }

    }

    return populatedPlaces

}

var simulatedUniverse: [[Int]] {

    return simAlgorithm.simulateUniverse( size, populatedPlaces: checkPopPlaces(populatedStringPlaces))

}

var universeCounter = 0

func paintUniverse ( universeArray: [[Int]], var uniCounter: Int, trueSize: Int ) {

    var placeCounter = 0

    if uniCounter < universeArray.count {

        for place in universeArray[uniCounter] {

            if place == 1 {
                self.realCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(returnTheRightCell(placeCounter, rightSize: trueSize ))?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            }
            else {
                self.realCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(returnTheRightCell(placeCounter, rightSize: trueSize ))?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            }

            placeCounter++

        }

        uniCounter++
    }
    else {
        timer.invalidate()
    }

}

@IBAction func startButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "paintUniverse", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

Comment: @matt Sorry for the lack of context, pleas check the edit and what do you mean by this is nuts?

Comment: the line that crashes: "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {". And the whole output of the console is in the edit

Comment: @matt my mistake, your last answer works, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most significant information in the crash log is

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Digiverse.SimulatorViewController paintUniverse]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f91c504c6c0'

The selector `paintUniverse` in the timer declaration line expects a method `func paintUniverse()` on the top level of the class without a parameter.

Your function `paintUniverse` has three parameters which cannot be used as a timer selector anyway.

A timer selector can have no parameters at all:

`selector: "paintUniverse"` -> `func paintUniverse()`

or one single parameter which must be a `NSTimer`instance and the `selector` must have a trailing colon:

`selector: "paintUniverse:"` -> `func paintUniverse(timer : NSTimer)`